# Using a provisioning profile multiple times

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am about to help a company distribute an App in house. They already have a provisioning profile set up that another app is using. Can i use the same provisioning profile or do i have to create another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a provisioning profile for more then one apps, but it means that the first app will be removed automatically at the second's install. Let's say, you have App1 installed on an iPad, and then you are going to install App2, and the App2's build was made with the same prov profile. The iPad will replace App1 with App2.
So: depends, what would like to do:)

Comment: Haha, i would not like the other app to be uninstalled :P Thank you for this answer!

Comment: @mollybaba Actually, App2 will be a new version of App1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Distribution provisioning profiles are created for a specific Application ID, that is - for one application. So it seems to me it's not possible.